# Force type conversions using Python C-API

Tags: python, c++, type-conversion, python-c-api

I'm wondering whether it is possible to use Python's C-API to convert e.g. Float -> String, or Bool -> Int, or Int -> Bool etc

Not every conversion makes sense, for example Dict -> List -- it would be hard to imagine what this would look like.

However, most conversions DO make sense.

```
Float -> Int     would just round to the nearest integer
Float -> Bool    would evaluate True non-zero
Float -> String  would give a string representation (but to what precision?)
Float -> Dict    probably doesn't make sense
```

So my question is, is there any way to force these type conversions using the C-API?

I understand that Python's preferred way of doing things is to handle the type internally. So you do:

```
x = 1 + 2.5
```

And it is smart enough to know that Long + Float -> Float

However, I'm writing a Python/C++ bridge where I have Long Float Complex Dict etc types, and I want to be able to do:

```
// initialise a Float object with an object of unknown type
Float myFloat = somePyObjectPointer;
```

So initialising it with an integer would work, a string "3.14" would work, "foo" wouldn't, a Dict wouldn't, etc.

I would like to use Python's machinery for "what plugs into what" rather than build a large amount of C++ machinery to do it manually.  Rationale is (1) less C++, (2) if CPython changes functionality I don't want to be out of sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Float -> Int

[`PyNumber_Int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Int)

> Float -> Bool

No direct conversion, but [`PyObject_IsTrue()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsTrue) and [`PyBool_FromLong()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/bool.html#c.PyBool_FromLong)

> Float -> String

[`PyObject_Repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Repr) or [`PyObject_Str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str)

> Dict -> List

[`PyObject_CallMethod(..., "keys"/"values"/"items", NULL)`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod)

> x = 1 + 2.5

[`PyNumber_Add()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Add)

> Float -> Dict

Yeah... no.

Anything you could care about, it's in there... somewhere.